# Regular expression ignore string if starts with specific substring

Tags: regex

I need to find with the regular expression domain names that don't start with the string "http". For example:

- https://domain1.com -> Don't match
- http://domain2.com -> Don't match
- domain3.com -> Match
- domain4.co.uk -> Match

I found a regex that almost got this:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}
```

But it also detects "https://domain1.com"

**Example given:**

https://regex101.com/r/DjDBrx/1/

In this example I want to avoid "https://domain1.com"

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Are you validating full strings? Or extracting from longer texts?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you want `/^(?!http)/` or `/\b(?!http)/`? I don't understand the `{,61}` and `{2,6}`, and your pattern has no `http` in it, so it seems to have nothing to do with your written specification.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm extracting from longer texts

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you :) {,61} and {2,6} are for detecting domains. It has no "http" on it because I don't know how to add it in order to ignore "http" at the start.

Comment: I would use something like `\b(?<!https:\/\/)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}\b`, a lookbehind with word boundaries.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is what I was looking for. Awesome, thank you very much.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this doesn't avoid URLs that start with "http://" (without the S). How can this be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a word boundary coupled with two negative lookbehinds:

```py
\b(?<!http:\/\/)(?<!https:\/\/)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}\b
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                ^^
```

The `(?<!http:\/\/)(?<!https:\/\/)` are two negative lookbehinds that will get triggered at the same location inside the string (since lookarounds are non-consuming patterns) and - after making sure the location is at the word boundary due to `\b` - they will fail the match if there is `http://` or `https://` immediately to the left of the current location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead, I think it is usually the quickest option.
It returns negative if contains the string you are excluding, like:
`^(?!(http)).*`

Comment: How would be the full regex? Don't know where to add it.

Comment: @Daniel The entire regex would be "^(?!(http:))". It will return everything that doesn't contain "http:"